# Sendmessage wm_paste textbox

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to copy text from another window then use SendMessage to paste the text in a textbox. I have tried using:

```
textBox1.Paste()
```

and

```
textBox1.text = Clipboard.GetText()
```

but it seems these paste functions are called before the sendmessage api, hence why I want a sendmessage api to paste to the textbox so it goes in the event order needed.

```
SendMessage(1508866, WM_COPY, 0, 0)
SendMessage(textBox1.handle, WM_PASTE, 0, 0) ' Does not paste anything in textbox.
```

EDIT:

Here is my code. Note, the clipboard method fires BEFORE sendmessage.

```
AppActivate("Hyperspace")
        SetCursorPos(2271,214) ' Request
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0)
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0)

        SetCursorPos(2726,111) ' Properties
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0)
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0)

        SetCursorPos(2681,792) ' Get EOW
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0)
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0)

        SetCursorPos(2853,525) ' Highlight EOW
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0)
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0)
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0)
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0)

        SendMessage(1508866, WM_COPY, 0, 0)
        textBox2.Text = Clipboard.GetText()

        SetCursorPos(2983,719) ' Close
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0)
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0)

        SetCursorPos(2967,783) ' Accept
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0)
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SendMessage()` is synchronous. It does not return until the message has been processed by the receiving window:

```
SendMessage(1508866, WM_COPY, 0, 0)
TextBox1.Text = Clipboard.GetText()
```

But why are you involving the clipboard at all?  If you have the `HWND` of the external window, you could just use `WM_GETTEXT` to retrieve its text and then assign it to the `Text` property of your `TextBox`.  No clipboard needed.

Comment: GetText will not work. I am double click the text i need in another app the calling wm_copy. The handle changes for the spot I need to copy, it is never the same which is why I cant use wm_gettext.

Comment: Furthermore, as mentioned in my original post, clipboard.gettext is happening before the sendmessage to copy. So, alas, that does not work either.

Comment: You have to know the target window's current `HWND` value in order to send `WM_COPY` to it.  If the `HWND` changes, you would have to get the new value before sending `WM_COPY`. So you can use `WM_GETTEXT` instead, as it would be sent to the same `HWND` you send `WM_COPY` to. And as I said, `SendMessage()` blocks the caller until the message is processed by the receiving `HWND`, so there is no way that `Clipboard.GetText()` would be able to run before `SendMessage()` is called/exits, unless YOU are calling `Clipboard.GetText()` first.

Comment: Edited my original post. As you can see, the code to set textbox2 with clipboard text comes after sendmessage. However, whatever i currently have in the clipboard ends up in textbox2 not what was copied with send message. (confirmed that after all code is done i paste to another place like textbox3 and i see the text that was copied.)

Comment: I guarantee you, in the code you have shown, `Clipboard.GetText()` **cannot** run before `SendMessage()` is called. What is more likely happening is that the `HWND` you are passing to `SendMessage()` is wrong, so `WM_COPY` fails and the clipboard is not updated.  You said yourself that the `HWND` changes, but you have hard-coded the value in your code. You will have to find it dynamically, such as with `FindWindow()` and `FindWindowEx()`.

Comment: BTW, you should be using [`SendInput()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310.aspx) instead of `SetCursorPos()` and `mouse_event()`.

Comment: Remy, please try to understand. The actual hwnd (child label) where the text needing to be copied is, changes. However, the x and y coordinates never change. Thus, I am able to set my mouse pointer there, double click (to highlight the text) then send a message to the main app window using it's hwnd (which doesnt change) to send the copy function. But, I can assure you the sendmessage is functioning properly. I can copy "random text" before i execute the code. When i run the code, "random text" is placed in textbox2. Now if i click textbox 3 and paste, it is whatever was copied by sendmessage.

Comment: You have to send `WM_COPY` (or `WM_GETTEXT`) to the actual child `HWND` whose text you want to retrieve, not to its parent window.  If you know the exact X/Y coordinates of that child, you can use `WindowFromPoint()` and `ChildWindowFromPoint()` to get the `HWND`. Or use the Accessibility API to get the text, which would be better than manipulating the mouse and sending `WM_COPY` manually.